# How to replace an apk default save data file?

Tags: android, replace, apk, default, data-files

I want to replace an apk default save data file .
For example I have an app and i set some setting on the app settings or i progress on the app and it works better and is better optimized .
I want to replace my now better optimized save data to the default apk save data file .
So when i reinstall or share the app
to on another device my setting or data is there by default.

If you can guide me in apk editor or apk tool or some easy way it would be really appreciated 
And is this even possible to do on smali changing with apktool ? Or i have to find a way to java edit it ?

Comment: Yes, apktool can be used to change the default values of settings of certain apps. But that require programming skills in Android/Java/Smali.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok .you know there is a save file in Android/data/ that saves whatever you do in the app . When you install an app a default and almost empty save data folder will be create that when app runs on it everything is on default and there is no progress on the app but if you replace that folder with another save data file from the same app but with actual progress on it ; the app will read the progress on the folder and continue from that state. I want to replace that default save folder with default and empty state to a folder with actual progress on it that whenever you share or reinstall the app

Comment: ""Continue from the last comment ""whenever you share or reinstall the app it goes straight to the progress on the folder and do not start the app on default settings and state . I hope i could show my point of view of exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the way you want, because the settings that are changed will be set in the data folder, of course the data folder you say is not the main settings folder, if your phone is rooted, you have access to that folder.

By sharing the app, you cannot transfer the settings or data on your phone, it is only possible if your phone is rooted and you send the main data folder of the app along with the app to the second phone. Be careful, the second phone must also be rooted.

So far this is not the answer of your

In order to be able to share the program with new settings, you need to enter the source codes of the program and customize the default settings from there.

For example, if you can select the font in the settings, and the default font is Nastaliq, and for example, you want to set another font, you must make these changes in the source code of the program. After making the changes, you can share the program with the new default settings.

Comment: Thanks man . I'm not sure about the root; in Android all you need is to open Android/data folder and everything is there and you can share it with little afford and replace files and etc...and changing app settings by decompiling it is a pain and most of the time we cant recompile it because of the signature problems ... And I'm most worried about progress but it's not a big deal because everything in save data folder will be recorded and by replacing that folder everything like settings progress and etc... Will be read and run as it is customized in the replaced file ....

Comment: If i can make the app run with new customizable data within the app's apk that would be great because it's going to be sharable without problem.